# FMX Timer editor

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

Does any one know where I can find a FMX Timer editor component that will work in windows, OSX, iOS and Android?

I need to be able to edit the hours, minutes, and seconds. From what I can tell both the Android and iOS time pickers only allow changing hours and minutes and includes an "am"/"pm" selection. I need minimally to be able to do the editing using the 24-hour format, include seconds, and preferably not be limited to a max of 24 hours. I would prefer not having to create my own FMX component if there are already ones available that do this.

Comment: Regarding am/pm: Are you sure that doesn't depend on the locale? I cannot imagine a Swedish Android system using a 12-hour clock...

Comment: That may be possible in other locales, but it is something I can't use regardless. I need to edit a timer value, not a time value. Also, the time pickers I have seen don't allow changing seconds, which I definitely need

Comment: Questions asking us about where to locate components are off-topic, as that would be an off-site resource. The [help/on-topic] says *Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.*

Comment: What about using the [TSpinBox](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/FMX.SpinBox.TSpinBox)!?

Comment: Have you tried setting the [Format](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/FMX.DateTimeCtrls.TCustomDateTimeEdit.Format) property of the [TTImeEdit](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/FMX.DateTimeCtrls.TTimeEdit) to `hh:mm:ss`

Comment: TSpinbox only allows individual numbers. I need the display in the time format. I did try setting the Format property of TTimeedit to hh:mm:ss, and it allows editing the seconds in Windows and OSX, but not in Android or IOS

Comment: So use 3 ``TSpinBox``es, one for hours, one for minutes and one for seconds. And put 2 labels between them containing a ":". Done! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I got a vague memory about the TTMSFMXDateTimeEdit component from tmssoftware. Not sure that is what you looking for but here is a [link](http://www.tmssoftware.biz/Download/Manuals/TMSFMXPackDevGuide.pdf)
its on page 122

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The TTMSFMXDateTimeEdit has the same problems. Only allows editing the hours and minutes, not the seconds. In addition, it appears you can't remove the date part of the edit.